# Add a "Did you mean" feature for tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I've seen over and over again the request to [fix tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request).

To solve this, the SO engine can learn from the corrections the users perform for a given tag. If there is a big occurrence of "editions" it means that one is common tagging error. The system can learn from these corrections and suggest the most popular one.

So here's how it would work:

- The **user** tags the question with a misspelled (or not so common) tag

  e.g. tag = `finaly`
- The **system** checks for tags correction count.

  The larger the number of "fixes" performed in the past, the more weight is given to a suggestion (so just a couple of fixes won't trigger anything).
- If the *"Did you mean"* threshold is reached the **system** shows the the question and prompts: *"Did you mean `Finally`?"* with a link to accept the suggestion (just like google does).
- If the **user** click the link, it means the tag is accepted (this would count as a correction too, giving more wight to the suggestion) .
- If the user ignores the suggestion nothing happens, the user entered tag is used.

References:

[How the did you mean algorithm works on Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syKY8CrHkck#t=22m03s)

Comment: @shadow-wizard wouldn't it make more sense to mark as duplicate the question that was made 6y later?#justSaying

Comment: No, the newer one is asked better and got better answers. (see scores)

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably was just less popular at the time. I read the linked question and it doesn't explain how would the system could solve the suggestion which this one does. I'll just drop the link of this question there.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, they check whether you're using the plural of an existing singular tag or vice versa. If you do, it says something like "You can't use a plural of this singular tag, raise it with meta if you disagree."

Comment: we do a trivial singular vs plural ... no octopi .. and we do a trivial mytag vs. my-tag bit of protection ... both are fairly recent changes

Answer (score 1):

**I don't believe this is worth the effort.**

Personally, if I am tagging something, I wait for the "autocomplete list" to pop up and see what the "popular" tag is that I'm about to type. That was probably the reason for adding the count of questions tagged with that particular tag into the autocomplete list in the first place.

and... I'd like to think that even with this in place, there would still be mis-tagging going on, and retagging would still be required. But when a retag request is made, the tool works just the same if there were only one mistagged question or 1500. So *reducing* the number of infractions is of no real benefit (short of the frequency at which a retagging must occur), unless you can *completely eliminate* the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like a "did you mean" feature, as it's confusing most of the time.

I'd rather prefer a static replacement table that auto-corrects *common* false tags (which then also could resolve stuff like SqlServer vs. MSSQL).

For the one-off-mistakes, the existing re-tagging functionality seems good enough?