# What's the possibility of adding a "Did you mean ..." in the tagging system?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

On some sites, and especially with new users, the format and function of the tagging system might be a bit unclear, so often tags get used incorrectly.

For example, one such issue on Arqade is the tag [fallout-shelter](/questions/tagged/fallout-shelter) - new users often type instead, something like `fallout shelter` ending up with the tags [fallout](/questions/tagged/fallout) and [shelter](/questions/tagged/shelter) - both of which (on Arqade) are legitimate tags, for two completely different games, and different again from the intended one.

My current understanding of how the tagging is managed is non-existent, so my suggestion might not even be possible, but what is the likelihood of adding a "service" that might detect this, and suggest the correct tag? maybe something like

> Did you mean [fallout-shelter](/questions/tagged/fallout-shelter)?

To perhaps further explain, or refine my idea, some sites offer a tag suggestion, that it picks up from the text in the question (as described above). Another part of that could possibly look at the tags you are using when you ask a question, compare them (possibly by looking at the tag wikis), and suggest an alternative, based on the suggested tags, the tags used, and the similarities between the two.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the system always recommend possible combination tags if two separate (legitimate) tags can combined into a single (legitimate) tag? Or, are you proposing another way of determining that the combination tag is a possible option?

Comment: @Andy, I was thinking probably something that might be ale to determine whether or not you are actually using the right tag. Like I said my knowledge of the system is non-existent, so that might be a bit too far-fetched.

Comment: Just trying to help flesh out your request. In your example, how would the system know the difference between `fallout`, `shelter` and `fallout-shelter`?

Comment: Possibly through some kind of tag comparison? Maybe from the content of the tag wikis? since `fallout` and `shelter` are two very different games, this new system might somehow see a similarity between `fallout` and `fallout-shelter`, and then see the `shelter` tag, and that would be another hint? There already is a system on place on some (if not all) SE sites that automatically suggests tags from the content of the question itself - so perhaps something similar could be implemented

Comment: The SO engine can learn what is the most common correction for a tag and suggest that. Just like the _Did you mean_ algorithm works on Google.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/add-a-did-you-mean-feature-for-tags) for a deeper explanation on how can be done.

Answer (score 7):

The likelihood is always between 0% and 100%. ;) If you're proposing a feature, I recommend using the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag rather than [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Having said that... as someone types in a tag, we do already bring up suggestions:

> [image]

Is this insufficient? What do you have in mind instead?

Comment: OP would like for system to check whether there's a tag combined for two tags just entered, because newcomers often put a space instead of the dash.

Comment: @nicael the hyphenated ones will come up, though. Perhaps a problem if not all hyphenated ones can be seen.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a limited possibility to blacklist a tag and suggest replacements. For example, if you try to ask a question with the tag `installation` on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), you'll see a popup telling you:

[image: “The 'installation' tag is not allowed”]

The “More info” link points to [a thread that explains the distinction](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7820/should-we-split-the-installation-tag-into-seperate-tags-for-the-installation-of), and the blacklist and popup was set up following [a meta request](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8233/blacklist-the-installation-tag). Only Stack Exchange staff can set up tag blacklists and popups. If you want one on a site, start a meta thread to discuss it, then a moderator will contact the staff once the discussion has settled.

This only works for tag names that are forbidden, however, so it won't solve your problem unless there's a workable alternate name for “fallout”.  Would “fallout-1” work? If you need to keep “fallout” as a tag name but it gets misused a lot, there is currently no good way to warn users. You should at least make sure that the tag wiki excerpt clearly states “for Fallout Shelter, use the tag [fallout-shelter] instead”, but most people don't read tag wikis.

Adding a popup for certain tags that are necessary but also misused sounds nice in principle. It isn't limited to ambiguous tag names; for example on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) we have the problem that many people use the tag [linux] just because they happen to be using Linux, even though the tag should only be used for questions that are specifically about Linux. The problem with such confirmation popups is that it's annoying when the tag is warranted, and it's largely ineffective because people click through without reading.